# How to implement feature extraction FAST algo in opencv ?

Tags: c++, windows

- What will be the output of the function of opent cv FAST algo implementation in c++ ??
- What parameters will this function will give as output and how can I use them to detct features ?

  ```
  void FASTX(InputArray image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, int threshold, bool nonmaxSupression, int type)
  ```